# Selection Sort in Python working in place

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I have written this selection sort algorithm which works "in place". I want to sort the following list: [8,3,1,7,4,10,5,9,2,6].
When I run the algorithm I get the following output:
[10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].

```
def selectionSortInPlace(listToSort):
    index = 0
    for i in range(0, len(listToSort)):
        value = listToSort[i]
        index = 0
        for j in range(i+1, len(listToSort)):
            if listToSort[j] < value:
                value = listToSort[j]
                index = j
        temp = listToSort[i]
        listToSort[i] = value
        listToSort[index] = temp
    
unsortedList = [8,3,1,7,4,10,5,9,2,6]
selectionSortInPlace(unsortedList)
print(unsortedList)
```

Comment: Change `index = 0` to `index = i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is that you set `index = 0` and `value = listToSort[i]`, and proceed with the swap even if the `for` loop didn't update those values.

One way to fix this would be to set these values to `None` and then continue the loop if they don't have real values:

```
def selectionSortInPlace(listToSort):
    for i in range(0, len(listToSort)):
        value = None
        index = None
        for j in range(i+1, len(listToSort)):
            print(j)
            if listToSort[j] < value:
                value = listToSort[j]
                index = j
        if index is None:
            continue
        temp = listToSort[i]
        listToSort[i] = value
        listToSort[index] = temp
```

Another option would be to set `index = i` so that it stays synchronized with `value` even if the `for` loop never updates either (this simply makes the swap a no-op in that case):

```
def selectionSortInPlace(listToSort):
    for i in range(0, len(listToSort)):
        index = i
        value = listToSort[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(listToSort)):
            print(j)
            if listToSort[j] < value:
                value = listToSort[j]
                index = j
        temp = listToSort[i]
        listToSort[i] = value
        listToSort[index] = temp
```

You can simplify the code a bit by making use of `enumerate` (which lets you iterate over the index and the value automatically rather than having to iterate by index and then look up the value), and tuple assignment (which lets you do the swap without a `temp` variable):

```
def selectionSortInPlace(listToSort):
    for i, a in enumerate(listToSort):
        k = i
        for j, b in enumerate(listToSort[i+1:], i+1):
            if b < a:
                k, a = j, b
        listToSort[i], listToSort[k] = listToSort[k], listToSort[i]
```

You can make it even simpler using the `min` function, since that will automatically do the inner iteration to find the smallest value for you:

```
def selectionSortInPlace(listToSort):
    for i, _ in enumerate(listToSort):
        j, _ = min(enumerate(listToSort[i:], i), key=lambda j_: j_[1])
        listToSort[i], listToSort[j] = listToSort[j], listToSort[i]
```

Comment: Hm this is tangential to this question and probably opinion-based but where does one put the line for in-place in Python … ? I think range is fair game but idk about enumerate?

Comment: As long as you're not allocating a new list (and consuming another O(n) worth of memory), it's considered "in-place".  `enumerate` doesn't create a new list, nor does `min`.